# Leaflet popup with live data

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, esri

I am fairly new to using leaflet maps, and I am trying to figure out a way for the map to display live data in the popups. Specifically, I am using current observations for the weather from the National Weather Service. Right now I am simply hard coding all the sites I want to use like this:

```
var marker = L.marker([41.15789, -104.80812])
     .bindPopup('Site: Cheyenne ASOS <br> <a href="http://w1.weather.gov/data/obhistory/KCYS.html">Current Observations</a>')
     .addTo(map);
```

I have about 100 sites total. Instead of the user having to click on the website to get the weather I am trying to have it displayed automatically when the site is clicked on. That way it would show the temperature, humidity, winds, etc.

If you have any insight or a place that I could find more information on this that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically insert data from the National Weather Service into your map, you can use the [National Weather Service API](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/)

From there, you can call the API when the page loads and then put the data in the marker. You can see how to do that in the [leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup)

For example, you can do:

```
var popup = L.popup()
    .setLatLng(latlng)
    .setContent('<p>Insert html to show weather info here</p>')
    .openOn(map);
```